# Proper implementation of OpenPrinter2 with PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE

Tags: delphi, winapi, printing, delphi-xe2

I'm modifying some existing code which uses [`OpenPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162751(v=vs.85).aspx) to instead use [`OpenPrinter2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162752(v=vs.85).aspx). It contains one more parameter [`PPRINTER_OPTIONS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162857(v=vs.85).aspx) which in Delphi is encapsulated as a `TPrinterOptions`, defined like so:

```
_PRINTER_OPTIONSW = record
  cbSize: Cardinal;
  dwFlags: DWORD;
end;
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to use this struct to encapsulate the flag [`PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162858(v=vs.85).aspx), and I can't even find that constant in any of the existing VCL/RTL.

```
var
  PD: TPrinterDefaults;
  PO: TPrinterOptions;
begin
  PO.dwFlags:= ???
  if OpenPrinter2(ADevice, @FPrinterHandle, @PD, @PO) then begin
    ...
```

I'm not having much luck searching for Delphi implementation of either `OpenPrinter2` or `TPrinterOptions`. How do I make `PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE` work?

**EDIT**

Is this correct?

```
const
  PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE = 0;
  PRINTER_OPTION_CACHE = 1;
  PRINTER_OPTION_CLIENT_CHANGE = 2;

...

  PO.dwFlags:= PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE;
```

Comment: Rather [`this`](http://pastebin.com/sjt0G2f2).

Comment: @TLama Ah So that's how you encapsulate a Winapi enum, eh?

Comment: What about the `cbSize` field?

Comment: @Jerry - You have to refer to the header file, each enumerator can be assigned an arbitrary value. If there wasn't any assignment, your guess would be valid.

Comment: @Jerry, well, you can write e.g. `PO.dwFlags := DWORD(PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE)` if you want (which is the most precise; keeping that enum translated literally). I don't see any benefit of it (in this case) since if it's a `DWORD` field, you won't get any type safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN docs say this:

```
typedef enum tagPRINTER_OPTION_FLAGS { 
  PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE,
  PRINTER_OPTION_CACHE,
  PRINTER_OPTION_CLIENT_CHANGE
} PRINTER_OPTION_FLAGS;
```

A C enum, as declared here, is really just an `int`. The first enum value is 0, the next 1, and so on.

But the header file tells a different story, contradicting the documentation. The header file says:

```
typedef enum _PRINTER_OPTION_FLAGS
{
    PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE       = 1 << 0,
    PRINTER_OPTION_CACHE          = 1 << 1,
    PRINTER_OPTION_CLIENT_CHANGE  = 1 << 2,
    PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CLIENT_DATA = 1 << 3,
} PRINTER_OPTION_FLAGS;
```

So translate to Pascal like this.

```
const
  PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE = 1;
  PRINTER_OPTION_CACHE = 2;
  PRINTER_OPTION_CLIENT_CHANGE = 4;
  PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CLIENT_DATA = 8;
```

Populate the record like this:

```
var
  Options: TPrinterOptions;
....
Options.cbSize := SizeOf(Options);
Options.dwFlags := PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE;
```

Comment: Hi. Have you created a custom Printers.pas that uses OpenPrinter2 instead, and if so did it fix the problem of getting the Error. Operation not suported on selected printer ?